# Call paint method from an inner class

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent, event-dispatching

I have a sample code that is simply to build a JFrame with a rectangle and a few buttons. I completed building the rectangles and now i'm onto placing two buttons, one start - top and one stop - bottom.

I have everything working, at least the science of it. However when i'm trying to set the start button to run the code nothing happens. I tried to see if there was an error by creating a JFrame and the code was successful. The JFrame is supposed to open with a start button that initiates the `paintComponent()` and the stop terminates the entire thing.

Is there anyone who could possible provide abit of guidance, i havn't slept for days trying to figure this outt.

```
    public static void main (String[] args){
        TwoButtonsRandomRec two = new TwoButtonsRandomRec();
        two.go();
    }

    public void go(){

        JPanel pan = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        START = new JButton("START");
        START.addActionListener(new StartListener());
        STOP = new JButton("STOP");
        STOP.addActionListener(new StopListener());

        pan.add(START);
        pan.add(STOP);

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, START);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, STOP);
        frame.setSize(500,500);       
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void GUI(){
        JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();
        frame2.setSize(500,500);       
        frame2.setVisible(true);
    }
    class StartListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                //frame.getContentPane().add(new DrawPanel());
                //System.exit(0);
                //
            DrawPanel panel = new DrawPanel();

         }
    }

    class StopListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
               System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    /*
     * Panel created
     * rectangle drawn to random sizes
     */
    class DrawPanel extends JPanel{
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                ran = new Random();
                g.setColor(new Color(ran.nextInt(255),+
                ran.nextInt(255),ran.nextInt(255)));
                height = ran.nextInt(getHeight());
                width = ran.nextInt(getWidth());
                x = ran.nextInt(getWidth()-width);
                y = ran.nextInt(getHeight()-height);
                g.fillRect(x,y,width,height);
                //repaint();
            try{
                Thread.sleep(240);
            }catch(InterruptedException ie){
            }   
            repaint();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The syntax of these lines are incorrect- `frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, START);` and `frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, STOP);`

Comment: It should be the `JButton` as the 1st parameter and the location constraint as the 2nd.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (incorporating the tips already offered).

Answer (score 2):

This snippet is a killer:

```
class DrawPanel extends JPanel{
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                ran = new Random();
                g.setColor(new Color(ran.nextInt(255),+
                ran.nextInt(255),ran.nextInt(255)));
                height = ran.nextInt(getHeight());
                width = ran.nextInt(getWidth());
                x = ran.nextInt(getWidth()-width);
                y = ran.nextInt(getHeight()-height);
                g.fillRect(x,y,width,height);
                //repaint();
            try{
                Thread.sleep(240);
            }catch(InterruptedException ie){
            }   
            repaint();
        }

    }
```

1. Never, ever,  call `Thread.sleep(240);` in the EDT
2. Never call `repaint();` from within `paintComponent` as this will create an infinite loop
3. Initiating `ran` once is enough, don't re-instantiate it over and over in `paintComponent`
4. The way you add your components to the frame is incorrect `(Component, int)` and not the other way around
5. Use Java coding conventions, ie, variables and methods are camel-case and start with a lowercase letter.
6. If you already add your buttons to a panel, then you only need to add that panel to your Frame and not your buttons. Otherwise it would mean that your panel is useless.
7. Don't forget to `super.paintComponent` when you override `paintComponent`.

Whenever you need a component to be painted again (ie, somehow you want `paintComponent`() to be invoked), invoke `repaint()` on that component.

Comment: @Timothy Edwards, And Lastly while you should never ever sleep on the EDT you should always get a good sleep yourself while trying to figure this out.

Comment: Thanks alot for replying, regarding the sleep, I only did that because I am not to familiar in the other techniques that would cause the rectangles to draw at a slower rate.
Also is there anything I can do in the StartListener that would call the paintComponent, i've tried everything I could think of that when I select Start but nothing works. The Jframe opens, stop kills the program but start just acts as a button. I should mention before I put those buttons, the program would run with rectangles flipping through randomly. Apologise but I don't know what else to do.Honestly tried all I know.

Comment: @TimothyEdwards Use a `javax.swing.Timer` and withing the `ActionListener` of that Timer, invoke `repaint()` on your `DrawPanel` instance (probably using something like: `DrawPanel.this.repaint();`).

Comment: Hey thx for all the help, still got some more fiddling I guess. I tried the `DrawPanel.this.repaint();` really hoping it'll work but was unlucky. I configure some more. Oh I wanted to asked, I created another method just for the kix of it to see what would happen if you press start and had the start button pointing to a method that would create an external JFrame and funy it worked. I even tried placing the start button to exit and that work. Just doesn't want to pull from the paint component.